# Functor Design Pattern in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I apologize for not coming up with a good title for this question. I'm having some trouble expressing what I need. I have a simple problem in Haskell and I am wondering what the best approach is to solve it.

Let's say I have a list of numbers: `[-3,2,1,2]`. I want to return the value with the highest absolute value. That is, I want to return -3. So I want:

```
f = maximum . map abs
```

The problem is, of course, that this returns the calculated value (3) and not the original value (-3).

I could figure out a way of doing this, maybe mapping the original list to a tuple of (originalValue, calculatdValue), finding the tuple whose snd is returned by my function (maximum) and then return fst of that tuple.

But this seems like a lot of "plumbing" for a simple problem like this, and I wonder if there is some abstraction I'm missing that solves this. That is, there is this generally procedure I do all the time, and I want some way of neatly doing it:

1. I want to take a list of items.
2. I want to map them to a certain value (let's say the absolute value)
3. Then I want to select one based on some criteria (let's say I want the maximum or maybe the minimum).
4. But then I want to return the *original* value. (If the list was `[-3,2,1,2]` and I want to return the value with the highest abs, then I would return -3).

Is there a library function for this? Is there a functor or a monad for this?

I think I want a function with the signature:

```
f :: ([b] -> b) -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
```

i.e.

```
f maximum abs [-3,2,1,2]
```

This feels very "functory" to me or maybe "monadic".

Answer (score 20):

Use maximumBy which takes a comparison function.  You can then pass some function that compares the way you want.

```
maximumBy (compare `on` abs)
```

Comment: Or equivalently: `maximumBy (comparing abs)`

Comment: I prefer using `on`, because it works with other things, e.g., nubBy ((==) `on` abs).

Comment: Thank you for your solution! There is a maximumBy and a minimumBy. Is there a findFirstBy? I guess there are a lot of functions that take an a and turn it into a b (abs), and then a lot of functions that take a [b] and turn it into b (maximum). And I'm trying to find a way of composing them generally without cooking it in.

Comment: @Ara: The `elemIndex` function in the `Data.List` module yields the index of the first element in a list which satisfies a given predicate. If there is no matching element, `Nothing` is returned. That might be what you're thinking off when talking about `findFirstBy`.

Answer (score 7):

Stop...hoogle time!

So you've got a list of stuff `[a]`. And you want to end up with just one of those `a`. You also want to compare elements of this list in some special way (not their natural ordering), in order to determine which comes first. This is the tricky part, but you should be able to see that what I've described is a function of the form `a -> a -> Ordering`.

Put it all together:

`(a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a`

And [hoogle it](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+a+-%3E+Ordering%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+a). `maximumBy` and `minimumBy` are the first hits :) Hoogle can be a powerful asset when you learn to use it. (See augustss's answer for details on how to use `maximumBy` in this case)

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do it, if the conversion is a bit expensive:

```
maximumWith :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
maximumWith f = snd . maximumBy (compare `on` fst) . map (f &&& id)
```

This type is similar to `GHC.Exts`'s [`sortWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/GHC-Exts.html#v%3asortWith), which gives us another way to do it:

```
maximumWith :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
maximumWith f = head . sortWith (Down . f)
```

We can define a minimumWith similarly:

```
minimumWith :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
minimumWith f = head . sortWith f
```

A look at the source for `sortWith` reveals that it's implemented by `sortBy`, so it lacks the caching that the first definition for `maximumWith` had.

This, obviously calls for some benchmarking:

```
module Main where
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Function (on)
import GHC.Exts (sortWith)
import Criterion.Main

sortWith :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
sortWith f = map snd . sortBy (compare `on` fst) . map (f &&& id)

badFib :: Int -> Int
badFib 0 = 1
badFib 1 = 1
badFib n = badFib (n - 1) + badFib (n - 2)

main = defaultMain [ bench "GHC.Exts.sortWith" $ nf (GHC.Exts.sortWith badFib) [0..20]
                   , bench "Main.sortWith" $ nf (Main.sortWith badFib) [0..20]
                   ]
```

The results on my laptop:

```
benchmarking GHC.Exts.sortWith
collecting 100 samples, 12 iterations each, in estimated 1.504415 s
bootstrapping with 100000 resamples
mean: 1.264608 ms, lb 1.260519 ms, ub 1.270248 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 24.42169 us, lb 19.21734 us, ub 31.50275 us, ci 0.950
found 8 outliers among 100 samples (8.0%)
  5 (5.0%) high mild
  3 (3.0%) high severe
variance introduced by outliers: 0.996%
variance is unaffected by outliers

benchmarking Main.sortWith
collecting 100 samples, 50 iterations each, in estimated 1.516733 s
bootstrapping with 100000 resamples
mean: 305.9089 us, lb 304.0602 us, ub 310.9257 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 14.41005 us, lb 6.680240 us, ub 30.26940 us, ci 0.950
found 18 outliers among 100 samples (18.0%)
  9 (9.0%) high mild
  9 (9.0%) high severe
variance introduced by outliers: 0.999%
variance is unaffected by outliers
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to have something ordered and compared by a projection always, rather than just at a specific usage (in which case see augustss's answer), then use a newtype wrapper:

```
newtype AbsInt = AbsInt Int

instance Eq AbsInt where
    AbsInt x == AbsInt y = abs x == abs y

instance Ord AbsInt where
    compare (AbsInt x) (AbsInt y) = compare x y
```

Now, for example:

```
maximum [AbsInt 1, AbsInt 10, AbsInt (-50)] = AbsInt (-50)
```

Presumably you would be working with `AbsInt` as your objects of study, so you wouldn't be writing those `AbsInt`s everywhere.

The more operations you need on `AbsInt`, the more boilerplate you need.  However if you just want to "pass through" some instances, `GHC` has an extension `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` that allows that; eg.:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype AbsInt = AbsInt Int
    deriving (Num)
```

Now `AbsInt` behaves like an `Int` with regard to arithmetic, but (given the instances above) by absolute values with regard to comparison.  Also note that the `Num` instance gives you the ability to use literals, so:

```
(maximum [1,2,-3] :: AbsInt) = AbsInt (-3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe something along the lines of the following should work.

```
foldl abs_max (head xs) xs
 where abs_max x y = if (abs x) > (abs y) then x else y
```

Looking beyond the task at hand you could generalize it by abstracting out the comparison function and passing it in later.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I cooked up. It's kind of meh, because it requires (Eq b)

```
selectOn :: (Eq b) => ([b] -> b) -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
selectOn reducer f list = head $ filter (\x -> f(x) == k ) list
  where k = reducer $ map f list
```

And then:

```
selectOn maximum abs [1,2,-3]
```

Or:

```
selectOn sum id [-3, 0, 3]
```

I guess I can generalize compare `on` and get the exact same effect.